Capture photos using EmguCV library in VB.NET
I'm trying to develop a Windows application using Visual Basic to capture photos from my webcam. I'm using EmguCV wrap library. Below is my code which is resulting in "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments". Can anyone suggest how to resolve this error?
`
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.CV.CvEnum
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class WebCamForm
Private capture As VideoCapture
Public ReadOnly Property InstalledUICulture As CultureInfo

Private Sub PhotoCaptureForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Initialize the Capture object for webcam access
    capture = New VideoCapture()
End Sub

Private Sub Button_CapturePhoto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_CapturePhoto.Click
    ' Capture a frame from the webcam
    Dim currentFrame As Mat = capture.QueryFrame()

    If currentFrame IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Convert the Mat object to an Image(Of Bgr, Byte) object
        Dim imageFrame As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = currentFrame.ToImage(Of Bgr, Byte)()

        ' Convert the Image(Of Bgr, Byte) object to a Bitmap object
        Dim bitmapFrame As Bitmap = New Bitmap(imageFrame)

        ' Display the captured image in the PictureBox
        PictureBox1.Image = bitmapFrame

        ' Save the captured image to a file
        Dim fileName As String = "captured_photo.jpg"
        bitmapFrame.Save(fileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PhotoCaptureForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    ' Release the resources associated with the Capture object
    If capture IsNot Nothing Then
        capture.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

End Class

`
Error Msg that I got:
Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error (active)    BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments:     'Public Overloads Sub New(filename As String)': Value of type 'Image(Of Bgr, Byte)' cannot be converted to 'String'.     'Public Overloads Sub New(stream As Stream)': Value of type 'Image(Of Bgr, Byte)' cannot be converted to 'Stream'.     'Public Overloads Sub New(original As Image)': Value of type 'Image(Of Bgr, Byte)' cannot be converted to 'Image'.   IFAB_Control_Center C:\Users\user\source\repos\IFAB\WebCamForm.vb   25   

No constructors of the Bitmap class accept an Image<Bgr, byte> as input, of course. Add the Emgu.CV.Bitmap package if you haven't already. Then you can use the .ToBitmap() extension method to convert an Image<Bgr, byte> to System.Drawing.Bitmap -- Set Option Strict to ON and keep it like that for all your projects

The following shows how to capture an image using the Emgu.CV NuGet package (v4.9.0.5494) and the webcam on your computer in VB.NET.
Try the following:
Create a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)
Change your project to x64 (or x86) see Emgu CV - Targeting .NET Framework

In VS menu, select Build
Select Configuration Manager...
For Platform drop-down, select x64 (or x86). If it doesn't exist, select <New...>. For New Platform, select x64 (or x86). Click OK

Download install the following NuGet packages:

Emgu.CV
Emgu.CV.Bitmap
Emgu.CV.runtime.windows

Add the following Imports

Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.BitmapExtension
Imports System.IO

Option 1 (CaptureImage):
Private Function CaptureImage() As Byte()
    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Nothing

    'create new instance
    Using frame As Mat = New Mat()
        'create new instance
        Using capture As VideoCapture = New VideoCapture()
            'capture video frame
            capture.Read(frame)
        End Using

        'save as bitmap
        Using bmp As Bitmap = frame.ToBitmap()
            Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                bmp.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

                'convert to Byte()
                imageBytes = ms.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return imageBytes
End Function

Option 2 (CaptureImage):
Private Function CaptureImage() As Byte()
    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Nothing

    'create new instance
    Using capture As VideoCapture = New VideoCapture()

        'capture video frame
        Using frame As Mat = capture.QueryFrame()

            'save as bitmap
            Using bmp As Bitmap = frame.ToBitmap()
                Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                    bmp.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

                    'convert to Byte()
                    imageBytes = ms.ToArray()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return imageBytes
End Function



Usage 1:
Add a PictureBox control to the form (name: PictureBox1)
Dim imageBytes As Byte() = CaptureImage()

Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(imageBytes)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Using

Usage 2:
Dim imageBytes As Byte() = CaptureImage()

Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
    sfd.Filter = "Bitmap File (*.bmp)|*.bmp"
    sfd.FileName = "Test.bmp"

    If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sfd.FileName, imageBytes)

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Saved to '{sfd.FileName}'")
    End If
End Using


To be able to view a live (ie: video) image (in a PictureBox), and then capture an image we'll need to add a Timer control to the form and refactor the code.
Open Solution Explorer

In VS menu, click View
Select Solution Explorer

Open Properties Window

In VS menu, click View
Select Properties Window

Open Toolbox

In VS menu, click View
Select Properties Window

Add a PictureBox to the form (name: PictureBox1)
Add Two Buttons to the form (names: ButtonStartLiveView and ButtonCapture)
Double-Click each button to add the Click event handler to the form
The form should look similar to the following:

Add a Timer to Form1 (name: Timer1)

In Solution Explorer, right click Form1.vb and select View Designer
In the Toolbox, expand All Windows Forms.
Drag Timer to the form (ex: Form1.vb [Design])
In the Properties Window, select Timer1
Set Interval: 33 (or 66)
Click 
Double-Click Tick to add the event handler to the form

Add Form_Closing event handler to the form
Form1.vb
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.BitmapExtension
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private frame As Mat = Nothing
    Private vidCapture As VideoCapture = Nothing
    Private imageBytes As Byte() = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonCapture_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCapture.Click
        StopLiveView()

        'ToDo: if desired, save image to disk, a database, etc..
        Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
            sfd.Filter = "Bitmap File (*.bmp)|*.bmp"
            sfd.FileName = "Test.bmp"

            If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sfd.FileName, imageBytes)

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Saved to '{sfd.FileName}'")
            End If
        End Using

        imageBytes = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'read 
        vidCapture.Read(frame)

        'save as bitmap
        Using bmp As Bitmap = frame.ToBitmap()
            Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                bmp.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

                'convert to array
                'this can be used to save the image to disk, a database, etc...
                imageBytes = ms.ToArray()

                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartLiveView()
        'create new instance
        frame = New Mat()
        vidCapture = New VideoCapture()

        'start timer
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopLiveView()
        'stop timer
        Timer1.Stop()

        Try
            'dispose VideoCapture instance
            vidCapture.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error disposing VideoCapture instance ({ex.Message})")
        End Try

        Try
            'dispose Mat instance
            frame.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error disposing Mat instance ({ex.Message})")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonStartLiveView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStartLiveView.Click
        StartLiveView()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        StopLiveView()
        imageBytes = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class


Resources:

Camera Capture in 7 lines of code
Set capture device EmguCV
Convert EmguCV image to system drawing bitmap


Thank You @user246821, With your code I'm able to capture photos. Could we see a live view and then capture the photo?

I've added the code. If this post has answered your original question, please click Mark as Answer and also click the up-arrow to upvote it.

@ASTRA: Did the code work for you?
